# How does Python multiprocessing.Process() know how many concurrent processes to open?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm running a script to take a list of database tables, check the row count of each table, and append the results of each query to a dictionary. I'm using multiprocessing to speed it up a bit: Manager to create a sharable list and sharable dictionary that the processes can read from and append to, and Process to set up the processes.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def main():
    mgr = Manager()
    # Function to get the list of tables
    table_list = mgr.list(get_table_list())

    counts = mgr.dict()
    for table in table_list:
        # get_table_count runs a 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table>' and appends
        # the result to the counts dict
        p = Process(target=select_star, args=(table, counts, 'prod'))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

My question is, how does Process manage the number of open processes? I'm accustomed to using Pool() with the apply_async() method, where you specify the number of processes when instantiating the Pool.

Any additional commentary on if this is the best method to use for this application would also be appreciated.

--

Thanks to dano for helping implement the two solutions below:

1 - using Pool.apply_async as I've been accustomed to:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, cpu_count
def main():
    mgr = Manager()

    table_list = get_table_list()
    pool = Pool(cpu_count() / 2)

    prod_counts = mgr.dict()

    for table in table_list:
        pool.apply_async(get_table_count, args=(table, prod_counts, 'prod'))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

2 - using Pool.map() with itertools.partial()

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, cpu_count
def main():
    mgr = Manager()

    table_list = get_table_list()
    pool = Pool(cpu_count() / 2)

    prod_counts = mgr.dict()
    func = partial(get_table_count, result_dict=prod_counts, env='prod')
    pool.map(func, table_list)

    print prod_counts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Process` doesn't know how many other processes are open, or do anything to manage the number of running `Process` objects. You need to use `multiprocessing.Pool` to get that functionality.

When you use `Process` directly, you launch the subprocess as soon as you call `p.start()`, and wait for the `Process` to exit when you call `p.join()`. So in your sample code, you're only ever running one process at a time, but you launch `len(table_list)` different processes.

This is not a good approach; because you're only launching one process at a time, you're not really doing anything concurrently. This will end up being slower than just a regular single-threaded/process approach because of the overhead of launching the subprocess and accessing the `Manager.dict`. You should just use a `Pool` instead:

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool

def select_star(table, counts, type_):  # counts and type_ will always be the counts dict and "prod", respectively
   pass

def main():
    mgr = Manager()
    counts = mgr.dict()

    p = Pool()
    func = partial(select_star, counts, "prod")  # Using a partial lets us pass extra parameters to select_start
    p.map(func, get_table_list())  # No need to use a manager for the list, since you're not passing the whole thing to the children.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: As an alternative to using `Pool`, he can also not call `join` right after each call to `start`. Instead, call `join` on all processes in a separate loop after all processes have been started.

Comment: @beetea True, but that would result in `len(table_list)` number of processes running concurrently, which could potentially be hundreds or thousands of processes. That is almost guaranteed to grind the system to a halt. And adds a whole bunch of process launching overhead. You really don't want many more than `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` number of processes running concurrently.

Comment: Yep, agreed. Was just suggesting an alternative since it seems he's aware of `Pool` but not using it.

Comment: @beetea Yes, I was curious about why the OP decided not use use `Pool` in this case as well. Perhaps because he wasn't aware of `partial`?

Comment: @dano I was not aware of `partial`, that's a good tip. I'm having an issue though because when doing `partial`, you passed in `counts` where `table` is usually passed in. So it seems the values are getting mapped improperly.

Comment: @PatrickBoocock, When you call `partial(func1, argA, argB)`, it returns a function object that can take a variable number of arguments, which will be passed to `func1` *before* `argA` and `argB`. So, doing `func = partial(something, "abc", "def")`, followed by `func("123")` is equivalent to `something("123", "abc", "def")`. So, going back to my example with `map`, each `table` instance will end up being the first argument to `select_star`, which is what you want.

Comment: @dano another question I have is why the method you described above works while the following doesn't:

`p = Pool()`
`mgr = Manager()`
`counts = mgr.dict()`
`list = get_table_list()`
`for table in list:`
    `pool.apply_async(table, counts, 'prod')`

Comment: @PatrickBoocock Use `pool.apply_async(table, (counts, 'prod'))`. The `args` in [`apply_async(func, [args, [kwargs, [callback]]])`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) needs to be a tuple or list.

Comment: Apologies, mis-pasted it. Seems to work fine after a little tweaking. Will post the solutions in the original post. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class):

> In multiprocessing, processes are spawned by creating a Process object
>   and then calling its start() method.

In short, it doesn't manage the number of open processes. It just spawns a process when you call start().